# SQLite property DB and GET {urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties seem to return some mismatching dbIds (objectIDs)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I try to get the dbIds of Navisworks items which have a specific property.

The NWDs get translated to SVF2, using the default settings.

When I query the property DB, I get different dbIds than the dbIds that are returned from the {urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties endpoint.

Query with results:[image: query with results]

Snippet of the corresponding json data:

```
[{
    "objectid": 11,
    "name": "3D Solid",
    "externalId": "0/1/0",
    "properties": {
        "Neanex Connector": {
            "ibcNAME": "Cone-1",
            "ibcGUID": "6453c4c067d1476db9c68c4066e291c4"
        }
    }
},
{
    "objectid": 2,
    "name": "SomeSolids-1.nwd",
    "externalId": "0",
    "properties": {
        "Neanex Connector": {
            "ibcNAME": "SomeSolids-1",
            "ibcGUID": "2613704afaeb4e68bcb1600a737df0b7"
        }
    }
},
{
    "objectid": 27,
    "name": "3D Solid",
    "externalId": "1/5/0",
    "properties": {
        "Neanex Connector": {
            "ibcNAME": "Wedge-2",
            "ibcGUID": "25d5fb2daebe4a3fb3eb1c671012d5f3"
        }
    }
},
{
    "objectid": 3,
    "name": "SomeSolids-2.nwd",
    "externalId": "1",
    "properties": {
        "Neanex Connector": {
            "ibcNAME": "SomeSolids-2",
            "ibcGUID": "425212b48a45457f9f9d5192e84bb0a4"
        }
    }
}]
```

Summary:

| SQLite dbId | External ID | json dbId | GUID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 2613704afaeb4e68bcb1600a737df0b7 |
| 6 | 0/1/0 | 11 | 6453c4c067d1476db9c68c4066e291c4 |
| 15 | 1 | 3 | 425212b48a45457f9f9d5192e84bb0a4 |
| 27 | 1/5/0 | 27 | 25d5fb2daebe4a3fb3eb1c671012d5f3 |

Which dbIds are the correct ones?

Why the differences?

Regards

Wolfgang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, the dbIds in SQLite DB will be svf dbIds. If you want to get svf dbIds after translating to svf2, you will need to call the below APIs with an extra header `x-ads-derivative-format: fallback`. Otherwise, the objectIds you got from the properties API will be svf2 dbIds.

- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-GET/
- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/

Comment: Thank you for the information that dbIds in SQLite DB will be always be the 'old' svf dbIds.   
The only source of information that I found about the SQLite DB is this blogpost:   
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-design-metadata-without-viewer  
Perhaps I missed some other documentation?

Comment: From what I can see, it's crucial to first use the `x-ads-derivative-format: fallback` header with the POST, otherwise the dbIds returned from metadata endpoints will always be svf2 format. 

See also:  
- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/

Quote:
3. If you use this header with one derivative (URN), you must use it consistently across the following endpoints, whenever you reference the same derivative.
- POST job (for OBJ output)
- GET {urn}/metadata/{guid}
- GET {urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties

Answer (score 0):

Two crucial pieces of information:

1. There are 'old' SVF dbIds, and newer SVF2 dbIds, see:

   - https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-svf2-enhancements-part-1-viewer
   - https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-svf2-enhancements-part-2-metadata
   - https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/temporary-workaround-mapping-between-svf1-and-svf2-ids
   - https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#headers  >  x-ads-derivative-format
2. The dbIds in the SQLite properties DB are **always** 'old' SVF dbIds

Using the header `x-ads-derivative-format: fallback` works fine, and you always get the 'old' SVF dbIds.

Note:
If you use this header with one derivative (URN), you must use it consistently across the following endpoints, whenever you reference the same derivative.

- POST job (for OBJ output)
- GET {urn}/metadata/{guid}
- GET {urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties